# boost on python on Mac

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost

I am trying to use boost library on Python. In C++ I include boost\python.hpp but it says it cannot open pyconfig.h. How should I do that? I have a Mac with Parallels installed and my C++ code is in Visual Studio on Parallels. I installed homebrew and boost from the terminal, I already had boost on the Parallels side which I have used different times in C++. In short, I did a mess. How can I fix this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find `pyconfig.h` on your machine, then add its directory to your build like `-I/some/path`.  Often it will be in a directory called python3.7 or whatever version you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks I found it. Now I am modifying the path of the files included by waterfall from pyconfig.h and so on. I am stuck with unistd.h. Python.h includes it but I cannot find it.

Comment: `unistd.h` is a file for POSIX systems like Linux, it may not exist on Windows unless you do something to install a POSIX subsystem there.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c But I guess more generally you should look for some instructions on how to set up the Python C API in your IDE, rather than bashing through it yourself.

Comment: I am using Python Launcher and IDLE on my Mac, any advice ?

Comment: Here's a question about Boost Python on Mac (without Parallels): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571611/boost-python-hello-world-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I am stuck with include<boost /python.h> is there a way to avoid this command? Can't I just use boost on python without C++?

Comment: @MarcoDiBartolo: What does "Boost on Python without C++" mean??  Boost is a C++ library for C++ developers.  Maybe you should start from the very beginning and tell us what you're trying to build.  Are you even trying to write C++ code that talks to the Python interpreter?

Comment: I want to use boost random number generators on python. I already have C++ codes that do what I want to do on python, so, if as you said boost is strictly C++, I need to use boost/python.h. I have been trying by modifying the paths of the files or moving them into boost but the file that gives me problems is cdefs.h, which gives me a preprocessor error

Comment: Which specific Boost RNG do you want to be able to invoke from Python?  And can you explain a little why Python's own RNG offerings, or those in NumPy, are not sufficient for your use case?

Comment: They are! I just wanted to take the chance to learn how to make C++ talking to Python